# Is there a method for solving equations like $x^{2}-\sqrt{x}-2=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a method for solving equations like $x^{2}-\sqrt{x}-2=0$?

As far as I can remember, I don't know any method for equations like this.

Comment: Well, there is formula for polynomials of degree 4, and this is certainly a polynomial of degree 4: $y^4-y-2=0$ with $y = \sqrt{x}$. Can you be more specific with the type of equations you're considering?

Comment: @Colin I think you mean $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}$

Comment: @Solid Snake The original question is to find the limit of the sequence $s_{1}=\sqrt{2}$ and $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{n}}}$ I already found that the sequence was increasing and had an upper bound. The question eventually boiled down to this. – Colin 8 mins ago

Answer (score 3):

If you use the substitution $u=\sqrt x$ you see that your equation is basically a quartic. Since we can solve all polynomials of degree less than or equal to $4$, there is a "method" to solve it, but it's not necessarily easy.

As it turns out, there are two real solutions to $u^4-u-2=0$. The first is $-1$, but that turns out to be an extra root introduced when we did the substitution $u=\sqrt x$ (we cannot plug $-1$ back in to the formula or we have a $\sqrt {-1}$ term).

The other root is near $1.3$, If we solve this back for $x$, we get $x=1.3^2$ which is near $1.83$.

Thus, there is one real root to the original equation which is the square of the second root given by [Wolfram here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%5E4-u-2%3D0).

Comment: (+1) It would be interesting to underline that since the (spurious) root $u=-1$ is easy to spot, the problem actually boils down to solving a cubic equation, namely $$ u^3-u^2+u = 2.$$

Comment: Actually, when factoring polynomials in an Algebra kind of course, I think $\sqrt{-1}$ is allowed.  Right?

Comment: Depending on context it could be allowed, but you can see that $i$ isn't a root of the original equation anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Setting $y = \sqrt{x}$, the equation becomes

$$
y^4 - y - 2 = 0 .
$$

This is a degree four polynomial equation. In general, it *is* possible to solve this kind of equations, but it is complicated and beyond the level a precalculus student should master; check the Wikipedia article on [Quartic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation) if you want to know more.

On a more basic level, it is useful to know that, once you spot an "easy" solution of the equation, finding the remaining solutions becomes easier because the order of the polynomial can be reduced. See the article on [Synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division) for a full explanation. In the case of the equation $y^4 - y -2 = 0$, it is easy to see that $-1$ is a solution. $y = -1$ does not correspond to a solution of your equation since it is negative, but that is not important. Using synthetic division, one obtains
$$
y^4 - y - 2 = (y + 1)(y^3 - y^2 + y - 2)
$$
so to find the other solutions to $y^4 - y -2 = 0$, it suffices to find the solutions of $y^3 - y^2 + y - 2 = 0$. This is slightly easier, since it is easier to find the roots of a cubic polynomial than to find those of a quartic polynomial, although it is still too hard for a precalculus course, I'm afraid.

Comment: If it means anything, this is actually just the tail end of a question about finding the limit of a monotone sequence in my advanced calculus course.

Comment: @Colin What kind of an answer does your teacher expect then? If the course is not about solving algebraic equations - which I presume it's not - then an answer like "The limit is the unique solution of $x² - \sqrt{x} - 2 = 0$." should suffice, I think.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments and answers, setting $x=t^2$ leads to $$x^{2}-\sqrt{x}-2=t^4-t-2=(t+1)(t^3-t^2+t-2)$$ Using the traditional test for cubic equations, there is only one real root to $t^3-t^2+t-2=0$ and, for such a case, there is an explicit [solution using hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root).

However, using [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), you could show that the only real root is given by $$t=\frac{1}{3} \left(1-2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{47+3 \sqrt{249}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(47+3 \sqrt{249}\right)}\right)$$ and $x= t^2$ is the solution required.

By the way, it is interesting to see how fast is the sequence converging
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n  &   s_n \\
 1 & 1.41421356237310 \\
 2 & 1.78583513096890 \\
 3 & 1.82656820977239 \\
 4 & 1.83071185729852 \\
 5 & 1.83113025486810 \\
 6 & 1.83117247019032 \\
 7 & 1.83117672929426 \\
 8 & 1.83117715899199 \\
 9 & 1.83117720234383 \\
 10 & 1.83117720671756 \\
 11 & 1.83117720715882 \\
 12 & 1.83117720720334 \\
 13 & 1.83117720720783 \\
 14 & 1.83117720720829 \\
 15 & 1.83117720720833 \\
 16 & 1.83117720720834 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: What is the sequence $(s_n)_n$?

Comment: @Bib-lost. I do not see what you mean. Which sequence are you speaking about ? Isn't $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}$ ? Please clarify.

Comment: Right, I had not read OP's comment specifying the sequence. Indeed, the sequence converges at a speed that probably surpasses a lot of numerical methods for finding roots of $t^4 - t - 2$.

Answer (score 0):

A *Mathematica* code for $\displaystyle{x^{2} - \,\sqrt{\, x\, }\, - 2 = 0}$ which changes its sign in $\displaystyle{\left[1,2\right]}$ such that the 'starting guess' is $\displaystyle{{1 + 2 \over 2} = {3 \over 2}}$.

```
(* x^2 - Sqrt[x] - 2 = 0 *)

dRoot[x_] :=
  Module[{den, num, sqrtX},
   sqrtX = Sqrt[x];
   num = (2 - x^2) sqrtX + x;
   den = 4 x sqrtX - 1;
   2 num/den];

myTol = 1.05 Module[{mp, x = 1.0},
    Do[mp = x;
       x /= 2.0; 
       If[(1.0 + x) > 1.0, Continue[], Break[]], {100000}];
       Sqrt[mp]];

(* Newton-Rapson *)
 Module[{dr, r = 3/2, rAnt, tol},
  Do[rAnt = r;
     dr = dRoot[r];
     r += dr;
     tol = Abs[rAnt + dr/2];
     tol = If[tol > 0, Abs[dr]/tol, Abs[dr]];
     If[tol < myTol, Break[], Continue[]], {100000}
   ];
 N[r, 50]]
```

Root $\displaystyle{\approx \texttt{1.8311772072083418533865654461108296451696466030113}}$

$\displaystyle{\texttt{myTol} = 1.77017 \times 10^{-7}}$.

> It agrees with [$\texttt{@Claude Leibovici}$ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1950189/85343).

Comment: Writing code by hand in MMA to solve that is pretty weird ;-)